# How to get the JFrame with the JLabel? Error when attempted

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to make minesweeper. I understand that there is probably a better way to do this but this is how I am trying it.

My problem comes in the gridSquare class. This class is a JLabel and I need the frame that the gridSquare is contained within. I attempt to get the frame with the line `minesweeperFrame frame = (minesweeperFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);`. The problem I run into is that `frame` is null and never set to the gridSquares Frame. Is there any way to fix this.

Main.java

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     minesweeperFrame frame = new minesweeperFrame();
   }
}
```

gridSquare.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border; 

public class gridSquare extends JLabel implements MouseListener{
    
    Boolean isBomb = false;
    int gridNum;
    int n1,n2,n3,n4,n6,n7,n8,n9;
    int bombNumber;
    minesweeperFrame frame = (minesweeperFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
    
    
    gridSquare(int gridNum){
        
        this.gridNum = gridNum;
        
        n1 = gridNum - 10 - 1; //Top left 
        n2 = gridNum - 10 ; //Top center
        n3 = gridNum - 10 + 1; //Top Left
        n4 = gridNum - 1;//center left
        n6 = gridNum + 1;//center right
        n7 = gridNum + 10 -1;//Bottom Left
        n8 = gridNum + 10; //Bottom Center
        n9 = gridNum + 10 + 1; //Bottom Right
        int neighbors[] = {n1,n2,n3,n4,n6,n7,n8,n9};
        
        try {
        //get the bomb number
        for(int i:neighbors) {
            if(frame.getSquares().get(i).getIsBomb()) { // if any neighbor is a bomb increase bombNumber ---------- frame.getSquares().get(i).getIsBomb()
                bombNumber++;
            }
            System.out.println("WORKS");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
        
        
        setText("");
        
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold",Font.PLAIN,20));
        setForeground(new Color(0x000000)); //set font color CHANGE FOR EACHER NUMBER
        setSize(50,50);
        
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray,5);
        setBorder(border);
        
        setBackground(new Color(0xd3d3d3)); //set background color ----- change to #424242 after clicked
        setOpaque(true);//display background color
        
        addMouseListener(this);
        
        
        
        }
    
    public Boolean getIsBomb() {
        return isBomb;
    }



    public void setIsBomb(Boolean isBomb) {
        this.isBomb = isBomb;
    }
    
    



    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                setText("Left Click!");
                
                if(isBomb) {
                    setText("bomb");
                }
                
                
                
          }
         if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                setText("Flag");
              }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}
```

mineSeeperFrame.java

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;


public class minesweeperFrame extends JFrame{
    

    private final int numColumns = 10;
    private int numRows = 8;
    
    int numBombs = 0;
    
    ArrayList<gridSquare> squares = new ArrayList<gridSquare>();
    
    minesweeperFrame(){
        
        setTitle("Minesweeper");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000,850);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(numRows,numColumns,1,1));
        setVisible(true);
        
        
        //Fill Arraylist and add to frame
        for(int i = 0; i < 80;i++) {
            squares.add(new gridSquare(i));
            add(squares.get(i));
        }
        
        //AddBombs
        while(numBombs < 10) {
            squares.get((int) (Math.random()*80)).setIsBomb(true);
            numBombs++;
        }
        
        
        
    }

    
    public ArrayList<gridSquare> getSquares() {
        return squares;
    }
    
    public int getGridRows() {
        return numRows;
    }

    public int getGridColumns() {
        return numColumns;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character. Learn by example and follow the naming conventions used by the JDK API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this during initialization:

```
minesweeperFrame frame = (minesweeperFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
```

the component is being created and not added to the frame yet, so you get null.

Moreover you add the gridsquare to the frame directly, this is wrong, you must add it to the contentPane, please read:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html